Avro Schema, refer enum values from json file
I'm defining an avro schema with an Enum field for a kafka topic. The avro schema will be uploaded to the kafka schema registry.
I do have a json file in a github repository defined as followed:
validValues.json
{
  "valueId": "abcd123",
  "values":[
     {
       "value": "ENUM1",
       "validDateStart": "2024-01-01",
       "validDateEnd": "2024-12-31"
     },
     {
       "value": "ENUM2",
       "validDateStart": "2024-01-01",
       "validDateEnd": "2024-12-31"
     },
     ....etc
   ]
}

From my Avro file, is the any possibility to refer the enum value from this validValues.json file?
I would like to have as values of the Enum fields in the avro file, the values ENUM1, ENUM2 ...etc defined in this json file.
Note that there are more than 100 values in the json file and there can change depending on the application configuration.  If there a changed, i want tje change to be reflected in the avro file.
Thanks a lot.
Thanks a lot.

You can dynamically construct an Avro schema from your JSON:
private static LocalDate getDate(ObjectNode jsObj, String fieldName) {
    return LocalDate.parse(jsObj.get(fieldName).textValue(), DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
}

private static Schema generateSchema(ObjectNode enumDescriptor, LocalDate today) {
    return SchemaBuilder.enumeration(enumDescriptor.get("valueId").textValue())
            .symbols(
                    StreamSupport.stream(enumDescriptor.get("values").spliterator(), false)
                            .map(ObjectNode.class::cast)
                            .filter(evd -> !today.isBefore(getDate(evd, "validDateStart")))
                            .filter(evd -> getDate(evd, "validDateEnd").isAfter(today))
                            .map(evd -> evd.get("value").textValue())
                            .toArray(String[]::new)
            );
}

Sample usage:
private static final String JSON = "{\n" +
        "  \"valueId\": \"abcd123\",\n" +
        "  \"values\":[\n" +
        "     {\n" +
        "       \"value\": \"ENUM1\",\n" +
        "       \"validDateStart\": \"2024-01-01\",\n" +
        "       \"validDateEnd\": \"2024-12-31\"\n" +
        "     },\n" +
        "     {\n" +
        "       \"value\": \"ENUM2\",\n" +
        "       \"validDateStart\": \"2024-01-01\",\n" +
        "       \"validDateEnd\": \"2024-12-31\"\n" +
        "     }\n" +
        "   ]\n" +
        "}";

public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    final ObjectNode enumJson = (ObjectNode)(new ObjectMapper().readTree(JSON));
    final Schema schema = generateSchema(enumJson, LocalDate.now());
    System.out.println(schema);
}

which outputs the following:
{"type":"enum","name":"abcd123","symbols":["ENUM1","ENUM2"]}


Hi Jon. Thanks so much for your answer. The Avro file is part of our spring boot project and the Kafka payload classes are generated from avro file using a maven plugin. If the avro file is constructed programmatically, how can I manage the generation of Kafka payload classes that I’m currently generating at maven build time?

If the JSON enum file is available at compile time, then you could translate the JSON file into an Avro schema file at compile time - i.e. by writing your own Maven plugin to do the translation. I appreciate this is non-trivial, but a) i can't see any other way to achieve it and b) it's probably not as difficult as it sounds (https://www.baeldung.com/maven-plugin).
